# responsive design framework where theres no max width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a framework out there for creating responsive websites where the width is not set? I've been using skeleton but that uses 960px and other frameworks uses around the same width. I need to know if it's possible to have a responsive website where regardless of the width of my screen, it will still work in a tablet & mobile?

Comment: pick a framework you like and override any width with percentage

Comment: http://xycss.com  <- that

Comment: the whole idea is that the width changes at certain breakpoints, so a 960 or 1140 grid will give you a certain number of columns with a flexible **% width**, see [here](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-mobile-960/) or [here](http://www.1140px.com/).

Comment: Twitter bootstrap? The fluid grid layout works based on percentages rather than pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hand code over using frameworks, but you should be able to just set the skeleton 960px width to an em or percentage value, as long as they have coded the innards to be percentage based it will still all work, code here that looks good to reset to % values: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/building-a-responsive-layout-with-skeleton-widescreen/ :)

Comment: Thank you for being a bad ass and not being lazy.  +1

Answer (score 0):

http://gumbyframework.com/ Perhaps? I just did a google search for responsive grids and there's a lot out there... unless I don't understand your question.